# Constraints check controller layer vs service layer

Tags: java, spring, rest, model-view-controller

I'm trying to learn spring and to achieve that i'm building a REST application from scratch. I'm confused where should I check constraints in my application: Controller layer vs. Service layer.
For example, in create user method I want to check if there is any other user with the same email, since email is unique in my database. I also want to check if password matches(password and "confirm password" fields) etc.

Currently, in my implementation, all this things are verified in Controller layer so I can return a ResponseEntity for every approach.

```
    @PostMapping("/signUp")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> createUser(@RequestBody RegisterUserDto user) {

        if (userService.getUserByEmail(user.getEmailAddress()) != null) {

            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("email already exists");
        }

        if (!user.getPassword().equals(user.getConfirmPassword())) {

            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("passwords are not the same");
        }

        User savedUser = null;

        try {

            savedUser = userService.createUser(userDtoConversions.convertToEntityRegister(user));

        } catch (ParseException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}")
                .buildAndExpand(savedUser.getId()).toUri();

        return ResponseEntity.created(location).build();
    }
```

Create user method in Service layer:

```
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public User createUser(User newUser) {

        newUser.setDateCreated(new Date());

        return userRepository.save(newUser);
    }
```

So which approach is better? If I checks constraints and validations in Service layer, what should I return so I would know in my controller why create user fails?

Comment: A useful way to think of this is as a funnel: Can I conceive of multiple interfaces that might want to update that record? (JSON API and HTML interface are two good examples.) If so, then that functionality goes in a common service that both interfaces use, which reduces duplication. (And in your specific case, you probably just want a case-insensitive unique constraint on your database column. You're presumably wanting to query on it anyway. Finally, use `Instant` instead of `Date` if possible.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my mind the best place to handle exceptions is the service layer. For my a REST controller method should, at most, handle the request and pass it over to a service method.

With this approach you have very clearly defined layers that do a very clearly defined job. For example your service layer will handle the validation of the request, the persisting action and also will provide (if needed) a return object to the controller, which then will wrap into the appropriate response object (`ResponseEntity` in you case).

With that in mind, there is nothing stopping you to throw any kind of exceptions in the service layer and have translated into proper responses. Spring has a very neat and powerful mechanism that does precisely that which is called an exception handler.

So in your case for the password checking action you could do something like:

```
if (!user.getPassword().equals(user.getConfirmPassword())) {
    throw new PasswordMismatchException("Passwords are not the same for user:: " + user.getName());
}
```

Where the `PasswordMismatchException` is a RuntimeException. With something like that, you can then go ahead and setup an ExceptionHandler along with the appropriate method to intercept this and translate it into a response. A simple example would be:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ApplicationExceptionHandler {

   @ExceptionHandler(PasswordMismatchException.class)
   public ResponseEntity<String> handleBadPasswords(PasswordMismatchException e) {
       return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(e.getMessage());
   }

}
```

You can read up for more on this on Spring's documentation:

[Spring ExceptionHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html)

[Exception Handling in Spring](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)